# How to fix 'object' must inherit from class “table” when working with summary.table?

Tags: r, list, qwraps2

I want to summarize basic stats of my data per factor. I have `10 different numeric variables` and `one factor (Segment_ID)`. I want `mean`, `max`, `min`, and `quantiles` of each variable per each `Segment_ID`.

I am trying to use the function `table.summary`, but when using it, it gives me an error:

> Error in summary.table(Data, My summary) : 
>     'object' must inherit from class “table”

My data has more than `2000 rows` and many many `NAs`.

I have tried to create the stats summary using the function list, and summary.table.

What I have tried:

```
Data=data.frame(Data)

Mysummary <-   
+   list("Segment 1250" =
+          list("min" = ~ min(Data$Segment_ID),
+               "max" = ~ max(Data$Segment_ID),
+               "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(Data$Segment_ID)),
+        "Segment 1409" =
+          list("min" = ~ min(Data$Segment_ID),
+               "median" = ~ median(Data$Segment_ID),
+               "max" = ~ max(Data$Segment_ID),
+               "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(Data$Segment_ID)))

 whole <- summary.table(Data, Mysummary)
```

I don't know how to fix the problem, it doesn't seem to be related with `NAs` because I tried with a data frame that had no `NAs` and also did not work.

Comment: You formatted the code as a quotation. I edited your question to format it as code. I'm not sure I didn't mess something up; please check my edit and update as needed. And please add a tag indicating what language this is (I don't recognize it, and I have no idea what an "NA" is).

Answer (score 0):

The error is a result of calling `summary.table` which is part of the base package and summarizes table.  You need to call the function `summary_table` witch is exported as part of the qwraps2 namespace.

You can call `summary_table` with the explicit namespace via `qwraps2::summary_table`.